# Oracle SQL query to return 0 if particular data has count 0

Tags: sql, database, oracle

My table looks something like that

So i write the SQL query to get data on 13-10-22 as

| Source_name | time | hash | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| America | 13-10-22 | vfdgh | Any |
| Africa | 12-10-22 | hgffgh | any |
| America | 13-10-22 | hhhnn | any |

```
SELECT source_name AS source, 
       COUNT(*) AS number_count
FROM mytable
WHERE time LIKE '%13-10-22%'
GROUP BY source_name
```

Output:

| source | number_count |
| --- | --- |
| America | 2 |

But I'm expecting

| source | number_count |
| --- | --- |
| America | 2 |
| Africa | 0 |

Please help.

Comment: you need to edit your question and 1) show the EXACT SQL DDL for the table, 2) sample data in table format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count conditionally with a `CASE` statement inside the `SUM` aggregate function as follows:

```
SELECT mytable.source_name AS source, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN mytable.time_ LIKE '%13-10-22%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY mytable.source_name
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/PjoGAfIt).

Comment: Thanks for your effort and if I have multiple conditions where exactly i need to put.. say for example WHERE data LIKE '%new_data%'

Comment: Inside the CASE statement: `WHEN mytable.time_ LIKE '%13-10-22%' AND <your_second_condition> AND <your_third_condition> AND ...`. Of course the more conditions you add up, the bigger the complexity will be, regardless of the solutions presented here.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding SQL order of operations. When you filter your table with `WHERE time LIKE '%13-10-22%'`, you eliminate the Africa rows *before* the `GROUP BY` or `SELECT` operations happen. You need to LEFT JOIN your summary table back onto the original table:

```
WITH
    counts AS (
        SELECT 
            source_name, 
            COUNT(*) AS number_count 
        FROM 
            mytable 
        WHERE 
            time LIKE '%13-10-22%' 
        GROUP BY 
            source_name
        )

SELECT
    sources.source_name,
    ISNULL(counts.number_count, 0) AS number_count
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT source_name FROM mytable) sources
    LEFT JOIN counts ON sources.source_name = counts.source_name
ORDER BY
    number_count DESC,
    source_name
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have well described why your query doesn't return what you expect. Here's another solution, using a CTE and COALESCE.

```
create table my_data (
  source_name varchar(20), 
  some_column varchar(20)
  );
```

```
Add your data
```

```
select *
from my_data
```

| SOURCE_NAME | SOME_COLUMN |
| --- | --- |
| America | TTT |
| Africa | CC |
| America | TTT |

```
with my_sources as (
  select distinct source_name
  from my_data
  )
select a.source_name, coalesce(count(b.source_name), 0) as number_count
from my_sources a
left join my_data b
  on a.source_name = b.source_name
 and b.some_column like '%T%' 
group by a.source_name
```

| SOURCE_NAME | NUMBER_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| America | 2 |
| Africa | 0 |

[fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fwX949Lb)